# How do I obtain access to a project repo when working as a Salesforce Developer?

Tags: salesforcedx, git

could you experienced developers please tell me, what usually happens (what is the standard process) when a Salesforce Developer gets assigned to a project, which includes Git as a DVCS system, for example:

1. How does one get access to a repository (will I be given new credentials or am I supposed to confirm with the project manager that my own personal Git account will be used for access)
2. Will I be told to pull data from master, create a new feature branch locally and then push that feature branch into Git?
3. After my work is done, do I reach to project manager for code review in my branch - do I do that before I send a pull request, or after I send a pull request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. Will the project repo be public or private? Will it be using a well known cloud-based git implementation (such as GitHub, Bitbucket, GitLab etc.) or will it be a private git implementation?

Typically development for a specific customer will use a private repository (which may be hosted by a provider like GitHub or may be self-hosted) and you will need to be invited or be granted access using an identity that is typically created by you during the invitation acceptance or that you were given when granted access.

Branch management and Pull Request/Merge Request management varies dramatically based on the development team's preferences and the project development approach adopted.

When using PRs or MRs, the review process usually works exactly by you committing changes and pushing them to the required remote branch against which the PR/MR exists and the review done against that. If using something like Bitbucket there is a web-based UI for the PR review process. In other cases the review may be done by simply looking at a diff (e.g. in an IDE) and providing review comments via some other mechanism, such as email or the work tracking system, such as Jira, in use.

Exactly how any of this works depends on so many different things you will find there isn't really a single answer here.